# SwiftUI - How to Save selected Image to CoreData and Retrieve it from another View

Tags: ios, image, core-data, swiftui

I'm using an image picker that allows the user to upload a profile picture. However I do not know how to save the image after its selected. This is the image picker code I'm using. Once saved I would also like to retrieve the image in another view and display it.

```
image!
    .resizable()
    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
    .frame(width: 150, height: 150)
    .clipShape(Circle())
    .overlay(Circle().stroke(Color.white, lineWidth: 4))
    .shadow(radius: 10)
    .onTapGesture { self.shouldPresentActionScheet = true }
    .sheet(isPresented: $shouldPresentImagePicker) {
        SUImagePickerView(sourceType: self.shouldPresentCamera ? .camera : .photoLibrary, image: self.$image, isPresented: self.$shouldPresentImagePicker)
    }.actionSheet(isPresented: $shouldPresentActionScheet) { () -> ActionSheet in
        ActionSheet(title: Text("Choose mode"), message: Text("Please choose your preferred mode to set your profile image"), buttons: [ActionSheet.Button.default(Text("Camera"), action: {
            self.shouldPresentImagePicker = true
            self.shouldPresentCamera = true
        }), ActionSheet.Button.default(Text("Photo Library"), action: {
            self.shouldPresentImagePicker = true
            self.shouldPresentCamera = false
        }), ActionSheet.Button.cancel()])
        
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not a good practice to save Image to Core Data, as you you'll need to encode into data while saving and decoding from data while retrieving. Also, I've read there are performance issues. The best practice is to use local storage to save an image, and Core Data saves a path to the image in storage. It can be completed like this. It's a good practice to set a unique image name like UUID()

```
func saveToDocumentDirectory(imageId: String) {
        if let image = takenImage, let data = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.7) {
            do {
                let filename = getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent(imageId)
                try data.write(to: filename, options: [[.atomicWrite, .completeFileProtection]])
            } catch {
                print("error saving data")
            }
        }
    }
```

You can call this function when you create a Core Data object like

```
saveToDocumentDirectory(imageId: object.id.uuidString)
```

Image can be retrieved with this method:

```
func retrieveImage(with id: UUID) {
    let dummyImage = Image(systemName: "person")
        do {
            let filename = getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent(id.uuidString)
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: filename)
            if let uiImage = UIImage(data: data) {
                return Image(uiImage: uiImage)
            }
        } catch {
            print("error loading data")
            return dummyImage
        }
        return dummyImage
}
```

Try using this image picker

```
import SwiftUI

struct ImagePicker: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    @Binding var takenPicture: UIImage?
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
        var parent: ImagePicker
        
        init(_ parent: ImagePicker) {
            self.parent = parent
        }

        func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
            if let image = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage {
                parent.takenPicture = image
            }

            parent.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
        }
    }
    
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }

    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIImagePickerController {
        let picker = UIImagePickerController()
        picker.sourceType = .camera
        picker.allowsEditing = false
        picker.cameraFlashMode = UIImagePickerController.CameraFlashMode.off
        picker.delegate = context.coordinator
        return picker
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIImagePickerController, context: Context) {}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for those inputs. The proper input is to add both the functions to the form view where the image picker is and then add 'saveToDocumentDirectory(imageId: object.id.uuidString)' inside the image picker correct. I'm learning as am building this app. Also what does the object refer to in the line of code?

Comment: My pleasure! As I understood from the description you have an Image Picker, you take a photo and you want to save it. I'm not sure about the context of your app, but let's say you build an app that will store a list of things you can find in a living room. Using a TextField you can name a thing, let's say a sofa, and also give it a unique identifier - UUID(). After the name is given you can call your image picker, select an image and save it using the ID property of the sofa. Next, when you want to retrieve it from the local storage you can just call `retrieveImage(with: sofa.id)`

Comment: Let me give this a try @Roma Kavinskyi if all else fails; I will load my app on git so you can take a look. Thanks for the help so far.

Comment: How's your progress so far?

Comment: I've not been able to move past. Trying out a different image picker by exploring the web some more.

Comment: I've posted a basic image picker for you. Try using this one!